# Fading Effect for Scrolling Lists in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, scroll, effects, fragment-shader

I am trying to create a scrolling list in OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android and I want the contents of my list to fade out as the list reaches the top or bottom. Right now I am implementing this in a fragment shader but it is very slow.

Here is my shader

```
precision mediump float;

uniform bool uEnableTexture;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform bool uEnableFade;
uniform float uTopFade;
uniform float uBottomFade;
uniform float uFadeWidth;

varying vec4 vPosition;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
varying vec4 vColor;

void main(){
    if (uEnableTexture) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord) * vColor;
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = vColor;
    }

    if (uEnableFade) {
        if (vPosition.y > uTopFade) {
            gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * 0.0;
        } else if (vPosition.y > uTopFade - uFadeWidth) {
            gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * (1.0 - (vPosition.y - (uTopFade - uFadeWidth)) / uFadeWidth);
        } else if (vPosition.y < uBottomFade) {
            gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * 0.0;
        } else if (vPosition.y < uBottomFade + uFadeWidth) {
            gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * (1.0 + (vPosition.y - (uBottomFade + uFadeWidth)) / uFadeWidth);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the effect I am trying to achieve.
[image: Effect screenshot]

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

EDIT: I was able to improve this a lot by using separate programs and using this shader only when I needed the fade.

```
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord) * vColor;

    if (vPosition.y > uTopFade - uFadeWidth) {
        gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * (1.0 - (vPosition.y - (uTopFade - uFadeWidth)) / uFadeWidth);
    } if (vPosition.y < uBottomFade + uFadeWidth) {
        gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * (1.0 + (vPosition.y - (uBottomFade + uFadeWidth)) / uFadeWidth);
    }
}
```

I could probably speed it up a little more by splitting this into two more shaders, one for the top and one for the bottom, or use uFadeWidth to determine the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would probably not to do the math in shader, but to precompute a 'fade texture' that would be 1 pixel wide, and as 'tall' as your viewport.

In this texture, you could store the fade value for every screen *y*.

Then, in your shader, you'd be left with another `texture2D` call, and a multiply.